# How do I combine multiple models into a single serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

it was necessary to combine several models(4) in one serializer, but there were problems with the implementation.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import FiltersView

urlpatterns = [
    path('filters/' FiltersView.as_view(), name='Filters')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK
from .serializers import FiltersSerializers

class FiltersView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filters = {}
        filters['model_1'] = Model1.objects.all()
        filters['model_2'] = Model2.objects.all()
        filters['model_3'] = Model3.objects.all()
        serializer = FiltersSerializers(filters, many=True)
        return Response (serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class FiltersSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    model_1 = Model1Serializers(read_only=True, many=True)
    model_2 = Model2Serializers(read_only=True)
    model_3 = Model3Serializers(read_only=True)
```

**But on the output I get:**

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are providing data to your serializer, `many=True` is not correct argument for it. Its a single object that you are passing to your serializer. Your view should be like this.

```
class FiltersView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filters = {}
        filters['model_1'] = Model1.objects.all()
        filters['model_2'] = Model2.objects.all()
        filters['model_3'] = Model3.objects.all()
        serializer = FiltersSerializers(filters)
        return Response (serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Oh, that was really my mistake. Thanks for the help.